# Laravel trans() not working

Tags: laravel

My directory looks like this:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            api.php
```

api.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'couldnotlogin' => 'Login failed, please check email and password',

];
```

But when I try

```
dd(trans('api.couldnotlogin'));
```

it will only output:

**api.couldnotlogin**

```
dd(App::getLocale());
```

returns **en**

other setting

```
'locale' => 'en',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where/When do you call the function? Because of the `;` I assume its not in a Balde View

Comment: @Webdesigner I just call dd(trans('api.couldnotlogin')); in a controller

Comment: In my case, my locale wasn't `en`. It was `en_IE` and I didn't have that folder in my project. I created the folder and relevant language files in that folder and that fixed it for me. You line `dd(App::getLocale());` helped me find the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

lang shouldn't be nested under assets. It should be nested under resources...  Thats why it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get your language variable in controller, if that is the case than you need to get via Lang

```
//Namespace
use Lang;

//in controller action
Lang::get('api.couldnotlogin');
```

Comment: Same result if I try it that way :/

Comment: can you let me know where you want to fetch the message, in controller or in blade ?

also the error you got is just because "function would return api.couldnotlogin if the translation key does not exist."

check reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-trans

Comment: I want to return it like this return redirect()->back()->withErrors([trans('api.couldnotlogin')]);

Comment: I also tried return response()->json(trans('api.couldnotlogin')); but same result

Comment: You can confirm the error message by checking dd(Lang::has('api.couldnotlogin', 'en'))

Comment: It returns false, but the folder/file/key does exist, look at my file structure above

Comment: can you try to rename the api.php to apis.php and than access variable using Lang::get('apis.couldnotlogin')

Comment: Yea I tried, it just outputs: **"apis.couldnotlogin"**

Comment: Just found the prob! lang shouldn't be nested under assets. It should be nested under resources.